# Pass authorization to SonarQube API using get

Tags: api, sonarqube

I want to access the SonarQube API and download all issues for the org I work at, I've seen the docs on how to access using curl :https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/web-api/ however as I want to download multiple pages I want to use get.

I have generated a token but can't figure out how to pass it in the request, using Python's request library, does anyone know how?